# How can I add php 7.0.0 RC2 in Mamp?

Tags: php, apache, mamp, php-7

The current version of MAMP that I have is php 5.6.10.

Is there a way to add the php 7.0.0RC2 version that can be selected in the MAMP interfaces php preferences?

This is for the free version of MAMP, not MAMP PRO.

I saw an old question ([How can I add additional PHP versions to MAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783558/how-can-i-add-additional-php-versions-to-mamp))

But I couldn't make it work because the php7.0.0RC2 doesn't have a module folder and I can't download the 7.0.0RC version in http://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/

Comment: You could always compile it yourself, and configure it yourself, if you *really* wanted that. Why did you expect there to be a convience package for prereleases? (Anyway, asking for [prepackaged] software is off-topic.)

Answer (score 2):

PHP 7.0.0 is available as *Standard Version* with MAMP 3.5 (free version). They also mentioned it in the [release notes](https://www.mamp.info/en/documentation/#versionhistory-version-267):

> Added component: PHP 7.0.0 incl. phpdbg (needs at least Mac OS X 10.8)

You're now free to select PHP 7 within the MAMP app preferences:

[image: MAMP 3.5 PHP Standard Versions]

I hope this helps, even though it's not the RC2 as requested.

Comment: What to do with existing MAMP?

Comment: @Volatil3 You can follow this [video tutorial](https://youtu.be/AczmvZJBR7A) on how to updating MAMP. I usually delete the old folders after the upgrade/migration.

Answer (score 1):

Bitnami has has added the ability to their "MAMPstack":

Download here:
https://bitnami.com/stack/mamp/installer

More Info:
http://blog.bitnami.com/2015/07/dive-into-php-7-on-bitnami-today.html