# MAMP 4.1 on Mac OSX only shows PHP 7.0.13 and 7.1.0 - Unable to load PHP 5.6.28?

Tags: php, macos, mamp, silverstripe, php-5.6

I've been using MAMP for a while now and the LITE version of MAMP has always shown 2 options for PHP versions and they have always been the latest of different versions, IE PHP 5.5.X and 5.6.X.

MAMP 4.1 only shows PHP 7.0.13 and PHP 7.1.0 - neither of which I'm able to use as I'm currently working with SilverStripe 3.5.2 which requires PHP 5.3.3 or higher, but lower then PHP 7.

[image]

Is there any way to disable at least 7.0.13 to get 5.6.28 to show up as an option to work with? I'd also rather not have to do a hacky solution so as to edit the httpd.conf or otherwise. I was looking for a more official way to change it ASIDE from upgrading to MAMP 4 PRO.

The documentation at the [MAMP website](http://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-Mac/Preferences/PHP/) doesn't seem to mention a way to do this - and I have tried changing the directory name under "/MAMP/bin/php/add-x-in-front-of-php-version-directory-here".

I am aware that XAMPP solves this problem for me, but I wanted to see if there is a solution for MAMP 4.1 before making the switch.

Comment: MAMP only shows two versions, you should rename the folders of the PHP versions you're not using.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783558/how-can-i-add-additional-php-versions-to-mamp

Comment: I've tried that, and restarted MAMP and the versions did not change. I added a x in front of them IE: 'x php7.0.13'.

Comment: I would have assumed renaming it any way at all would have the effect but this video shows renaming the folders with content after too, so maybe duplicate this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lHXwUXnq3Zw

Comment: There is a module which makes SilverStripe run on php7.   http://addons.silverstripe.org/add-ons/wernerkrauss/silverstripe-3-php7

Comment: @PhilS thanks for your suggested, I've answered the question myself so that it might help someone else attempting this same thing.

Comment: @GavinBruce I have not given that a try just yet, but that does look interesting and I will definitely give that a shot! But I did however want to solve this particular problem in the event the module were to give me problems and I would be back to square one.

Answer (score 4):

This problem was solved by instead renaming the directories from the other end as suggested by [PhilS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6809420/phils) in the comments from my original post above.

Renaming the directory from the 'right hand side' seems to do the trick as shown here in the image:

[image]

Now when choosing a PHP version it will skip over 7.0.13 and show 5.6.28 instead:

[image]