# Change PHP version in MAMP 5

Tags: php, mamp

High Sierra

MAMP 5.5

I want to change the version of PHP that MAMP is using, the method mentioned here, which I used previously doesn't work with MAMP 5:
[How to change PHP version on MAMP 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43137191/how-to-change-php-version-on-mamp-4-1)

I have removed the PHP version folders from the MAMP/bin/php folder, but still the only versions that appear in preferences are

7.2.21

7.3.8

even though these are not in the MAMP/bin/php folder

I have tried changing httpd.conf but my change gets overwritten when MAMP starts apache:

```
LoadModule php5_module        /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.40/modules/libphp5.so
#LoadModule php7_module        /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.3.8/modules/libphp7.so
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Use Laragon, You will fall in love with it. Much More features and easy to play with all php version, support most databases

Comment: I don't use windows

Comment: have you tried adding `PATH` to `.bash_profile`. I had done on High Sierra for MAMP 5.5

Answer (score 1):

At any given time the MAMP->Preferences->PHP will allow you to select among only two versions only.

Refer this [link about how to change PHP versions](https://www.igorkromin.net/index.php/2017/08/07/how-to-addchange-php-versions-appearing-in-mamp-preferences/) in MAMP->Preferences->PHP option.

Comment: But that's exactly what I have explained that I've already tried and didn't work!

Comment: Do you mean to say that the references i gave  https://www.igorkromin.net/index.php/2017/08/07/how-to-addchange-php-versions-appearing-in-mamp-preferences/ is not working on your mac ?

Comment: the link you provided has exactly the same information as posts in the link I included in my question, which I said did not work

Comment: You can try updating you mamp to latest version. The solution i discussed in this post is working properly on my mac. The latest version is 5.5.