# Missed exstensions for php 7.1 on Catalina os

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

How to install PHP 7.1 on mac Catalina OS?

I have PHP 7.4 installed from brew. I need two versions of PHP 7.4 and 7.1.

I install `curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.1` and got error a lot missed extensions. I don't find these extensions on mac.

Comment: Kindly post your error and explain your question more.

Answer (score 0):

Try [MAMP & MAMP Pro](https://www.mamp.info/en/) in order to manage and switch between PHP versions, take a look here: [How to change PHP versionon MAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43137191/how-to-change-php-version-on-mamp-4-1)

Comment: Yesterday i install xampp. In xampp also missed exstensions for php 7.1. I wil try with mamp.

Comment: I there some solution to install php and apache without xampp or mamp.?

Comment: Look [this one](https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-catalina-apache-multiple-php-versions)

Comment: yap, I messed up everything when updated php from brew, i try with removing all php version from brew