# phpinfo() is not showing me that the mongodb is installed on my mac

Tags: php, mongodb

I just installed the mongodb on my mac pc. If I run this command:

> php --ri mongodb

I can see it's successfully installed:

```
mongodb

MongoDB support => enabled
MongoDB extension version => 1.14.1
MongoDB extension stability => stable
libbson bundled version => 1.22.1
libmongoc bundled version => 1.22.1
libmongoc SSL => enabled
libmongoc SSL library => Secure Transport
libmongoc crypto => enabled
libmongoc crypto library => Common Crypto
libmongoc crypto system profile => disabled
libmongoc SASL => enabled
libmongoc ICU => disabled
libmongoc compression => enabled
libmongoc compression snappy => disabled
libmongoc compression zlib => enabled
libmongoc compression zstd => enabled
libmongocrypt bundled version => 1.5.2
libmongocrypt crypto => enabled
libmongocrypt crypto library => Common Crypto

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
mongodb.debug => no value => no value
```

But using the `phpinfo()` output I can't see it's installed. I also add this:

```
extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.1.11/pecl/20210902/mongodb.so"
```

to php.ini file.

Any idea?

Comment: PHP via Web and CLI can, and usually do, have their own ini files.

Comment: can you share your phpinfo(); output?

Comment: @Rudra how can I share the full output ? It's too big, you know

Comment: You can share a screenshot but no problem, Okay, can you check if php versions are same in your phpinfo() output in browser and cli? @Shibbir

Comment: Using phpinfo() I can see my php version is 7.4.2.1 but how can I check using cli?

Comment: Use php -v, it seems there is version difference with your server and cli

Comment: OH, No it's different. It's 8.1.11

Comment: I am writing the answer, which server are you using?

Comment: @Rudra It's MAMP.

Comment: @Shibbir you need to change the php version mamp is using can you refer this one for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43137191/how-to-change-php-version-on-mamp-4-1

Comment: Let me check it.

Comment: Kindly check this image: https://prnt.sc/O2lMk44Oay94, I have php 7.4 and 7.3 exist and its also enable by MAMP https://prnt.sc/Xf26PR-uI2qY. Then how this 8.1.11 is coming

Comment: You might have installed php8.1 unknowingly

Comment: Can you try to change php cli version back to php 7.4? https://gist.github.com/irazasyed/5987693

Comment: Using `whereis php` command I can see 2 result : `php: /usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/share/man/man1/php.1` does it mean I have 2 PHP installed ?

Comment: Yes this can be issue can you check version for each path by using "/usr/local/share/man/man1/php.1 -v"

Comment: @Rudra can you come to chat discussion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248558/discussion-between-shibbir-and-rudra).

Comment: @Shibbir Can you accept my answer as it helped you in fixing your issue, so it is helpful to other users, who face similar issue. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248558/discussion-between-shibbir-and-rudra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our discussion ,
Your server is using different php version then your cli,
CLI has installed mongodb in php 8.1 and server is using php 7.4

to change php version MAMP is using please refer to this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44384509/12987235

Or you can use the mamp's php in cli, refer below link to use mamp's PHP
https://www.choosepizzi.net/mamp-lets-make-terminal-use-mamps-php-instead-of-macs-version/

---

Comment: You helped me a lot and save my day !